# Performance issue with this AWK - This Code takes around 200 mins on 5GB input file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Below code runs on 5GB file and it consumes 99% CPU, I wanted to know if I am doing something terribly wrong or anything can improve execution time.

2013-04-03 08:54:19,989 INFO  [Logger] 2013-04-03T08:54:19.987-04:00PCMC.common.manage.springUtil<log-message-body><headers>&lt;fedDKPLoggingContext id="DKP_DumpDocumentProperties" type="context.generated.FedDKPLoggingContext"&gt;&lt;logFilter&gt;7&lt;/logFilter&gt;&lt;logSeverity&gt;255&lt;/logSeverity&gt;&lt;schemaType&gt;PCMC.MRP.DocumentMetaData&lt;/schemaType&gt;&lt;UID&gt;073104c-4e-4ce-bda-694344ee62&lt;/UID&gt;&lt;consumerSystemId&gt;JTR&lt;/consumerSystemId&gt;&lt;consumerLogin&gt;jbserviceid&lt;/consumerLogin&gt;&lt;logLocation&gt;Successful Completion of    Service&lt;/logLocation&gt;&lt;/fedDKPLoggingContext&gt;</headers><payload>0</payload></log-message-body>

This is the code I am using. I tried with gz format also but all in vain. And I am call this awk from bash this below command.

awk -f mytest.awk <(gzip -dc scanned-file.$yesterday.gz)| gzip > tem.gz

```
cat mytest.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

function to_ms (time, time_ms, s) {
    split(time, s, /:|\,/ )
    time_ms = (s[1]*3600+s[2]*60+s[3])*1000+s[4]
    #printf ("%s\n", newtime)
    return time_ms
}

{
   stid = gensub(/.*UID&amp;gt;([^&]+).*/,"\\1","")
}

(stid in starttime) {
    etime = to_ms($2)
    endtime[stid] = etime
    docid[stid] = gensub(/.*id="([^""]+).*/,"\\1","")
    consumer[stid]= gensub(/.*schemaType&amp;gt;PNC.([^.]+).*/,"\\1","")
    state[stid]= gensub(/.*lt;logLocation&amp;gt;([^'' ]+).*/,"\\1","")
    next
}

{
    stime = to_ms($2)
    starttime[stid] = stime
    st_hour[stid] = stime/(60*60*1000)
    timestamp[stid] = $1" "$2
}

END {
    print "Document,Consumer,Hour,ResponseTime,Timestamp,State"
    for (x in starttime) {
        for (y in endtime) {
            if (x==y) {
                diff = (endtime[y]-starttime[x])
                st = sprintf("%02d", st_hour[x])
                print docid[y], consumer[y], st":00", diff, timestamp[x], state[y] |"sort -k3"
                delete starttime[x]
                delete endtime[y]
                delete docid[y]
                delete consumer[y]
                delete timestamp[x]
                delete state[y]
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's just one end time for every stid - don't build up an array of start times and an array of end times and then loop through them both, just process the stid when you hit it's end time. i.e. not this as you do today:

```
{ stid = whatever }
stid in starttime {
   populate endtime[stid]
   next
}
{ populate starttime[stid] }
END {
   for (x in starttime) {
      for (y in endtime) {
          if (x == y) {
              stid = x
              process endtime[stid] - starttime[stid]
          }
      }
   }
}
```

but this:

```
{ stid = whatever }
stid in starttime {
   process to_ms($2) - starttime[stid]
   delete starttime[stid]
   next
}
{ populate starttime[stid] }
```

If you can't do that, e.g. due to there being multiple records with the same stid and you want to get the time stamps from the first and last ones, then change the loop in your END section to just loop through the stids that you got endtimes for (since you already KNOW they have corresponding starttimes) instead of trying to find all the stids in those massive loops on starttime and endtime, e.g.:

```
{ stid = whatever }
stid in starttime {
   populate endtime[stid]
   next
}
{ populate starttime[stid] }
END {
   for (stid in endtime) {
      process endtime[stid] - starttime[stid]
   }
}
```

With either approach you should see a massive performance improvement.

Comment: if the request is successful then every uniques stid have only one start and only one end time. and if the request is failed there will be one stid with start time only.

Comment: Good then you can use the first approach I suggested above which is the most efficient approach. If you want to find the failure cases too, add a loop in the END to loop through all of the stids remaining in starttime since the success cases will delete the stids as they are processed. Please let us know what impact my suggestion has on the time it takes to process your records as I'm curious.

Comment: @ Ed, first approach didnt go through well..but 2nd one worked like charm, i ran a test and it took 15 mins..awesome improvement, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

In the `END` section it always goes through the internal [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), even if the `y` item is found and then deleted from the `endtime` array. I would suggest to use a `break` to jump out of the internal loop.

On the other hand (as I see) the internal loop is not needed at all! It tries to find an element with a known key in an associative array.

Also I may suggest no to delete the found items. To find an item in associative array is done in constant time (depending on the hash key generated algorithm and how many duplicated items are generated), so removing items from such array will not necessarily speed up the process, but the deletion of items will definitely slow it down.

So I may suggest to use this:

```
for (x in starttime) {
    if (x in endtime) {
        diff = (endtime[x]-starttime[x])
        st = sprintf("%02d", st_hour[x])
        print docid[x], consumer[x], st":00", diff, timestamp[x], state[x] |"sort -k3"
    }
}
```

Using [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip) will even consume more CPU resources, but You can spare some I/O bandwidth.

Comment: @random_thoughts: Ok. Also I would move `sort` after `awk`, but it is only for cleaner coding. Anyway how many items are in the `starttime` array?

Comment: Yes sort can be moved after awk, starttime items are around 200,000

Comment: @random_thoughts: Aha! 2e5*2e5 is a huge number! :)

Comment: @random_thoughts: I also was thinking about that if there is an upper limit to a line in the log file and you have multiple cores in your PC then multiple `dd ...|awk ...` pipes could be started to read different (and a little bit overlapping) chunks of the file and preprocess the huge file. Depending on the underlying I/O architecture it can speed up the whole process.

Comment: I didnt understand meaning of " upper limit to a line"

Comment: @random_thoughts: I meant max. length.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33332/discussion-between-truey-and-random-thoughts)

Comment: @random_thoughts I have tested starting multiple `dd ... | awk ...` on a two core laptop, with a single hdd and it seems not a great idea. Could you test your code with my modification? Is it better? On the other hand you could comment the END section to check where the big time is spent.

Comment: I have testes with only looping over end time in END Section and it worked great. Your idea was usefull too..Thanks

Comment: Chat is restricted in my env :-( Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

@ Ed, first approach is not giving me expected result. this is what did

```
# end time and diff 
(stid in starttime) 
{ etime = to_ms($2) 
diff = etime - stime
 print diff,stid 
delete starttime[stid] 
next } 
# Populate starttime
 { 
stime = to_ms($2) 
starttime[stid] = stime 
st_hour[stid] = stime/(60*60*1000)
 }
```

o/p
 is like left this sud come in milisecond and with stid.

561849 c858591f-e01b-4407-b9f9-48302b65c383
562740 c858591f-e01b-4407-b9f9-48302b65c383 
563629 56c71ef3-d952-4261-9711-16b18a32c6ba 
564484 56c71ef3-d952-4261-9711-16b18a32c6ba

Comment: You need to move the first `{` to be on the same line as `stid in starttime` and to populate `stid` before any of that.

Comment: in this approach, if the request doesnt have end time, how would it go?

Comment: Same as the other approach - you'd have an array of un-resolved starttime[stid]s that you could process in a loop in the END section.